# Condition for template, using Agent.OS | AGENT_OS

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want include a template depending on the variable Agent.OS:

```
...
steps:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux') }}:
    - template: /templates/prepare-tool.yaml
```

But this does not work. I don't see this step on the list of steps.
I tried also:

```
  - ${{ if eq(variables.AGENT_OS, 'Linux') }}:
```

The same result.

Maybe I'm wrong, but:

> The difference between runtime and compile time expression syntaxes is primarily what context is available. In a compile-time expression (${{  }}), you have access to parameters and statically defined variables. In a runtime expression ($[  ]), you have access to more variables but no parameters.

So, I have to use `- $[ if eq(...` for this variable, which is not static, but it does not work either:

> Unexpected value '$[ if eq(variables.

I don't have idea how to use this kind of variable.

From what I found on stackoverflow(eg. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70339669/can-azure-devops-build-variable-build-reason-be-used-in-yaml-template-compile-ti), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412452/execute-or-not-template-in-azure-pipeline-with-runtime-condition)) this is impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Condition for template, using Agent.OS | AGENT_OS

Yes, you are right. There is no out of box way to do this.

Since the value of the variable `Agent.OS` is a runtime variable, we could not use it before we run the job.

And the variable `${{ if eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux') }}` is a compile-time variable. So, Therefore, the judgment result of the condition is always a failure.

To resolve this issue, you could add the condition to the template for each step, like:

```
steps:
- script: echo Sometimes this happens!
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux'))
```

Comment: Yes, I made it in this way. I had only a few tasks, which I compressed into one.

Comment: @piecia, so, if above answer help you, you could accept it

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to accept this answer because there is no better solution. Sometime I really hate Azure pipelines :) Fortunately I use simple templates, with a few steps, so it's not a problem.